# Sharepoint getlistitems not returning list items

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm a bit new to spservices, and I hope I'm not asking a question that's already been answered. I **have** checked and have not been able to find another question that addressed the same issue as this. I'm using GetListItems to retrieve url's and titles stored in a list. Right now I'm retrieving items and just displaying them in a temporary table.

It works perfectly in a little html page that I've created that references the js files, jquery, etc.

But,

When I set a Content Editor Web Part to point to the html file (using the Content Link), the javascript doesn't work, (or something), and the items aren't displayed. I found out where exactly it stopped working:

```
 $().SPServices({
                operation: method,
                async: false,
                listName: list,
                CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
                  CAMLQuery: query,
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         alert("When it's in the Content Editor Web Part, this gets called");
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
         alert("but this does not");
                            var hyperlink = ($(this).attr("ows_Hyperlink")).split(",");
                            var url = hyperlink[0];
                            var description = hyperlink[1];


                            AddRowToTable(url,description);

                        });                
                    }
        });
```

As I said before, this code works perfectly when I go to the physical address of the html page. It grabs the list items and displays the correct things. The problems occur when I reference, through the Content Link, the html page in the Content Editor Web Part. If anyone has insight on this, it would be most welcome.

Thanks, AA

Comment: If you use something like firebug or other dev tool in your browser of choice, are there any javascript console errors/notifications?  If I were to guess, I would think that maybe jQuery isn't being imported correctly.

Comment: Ah, I am getting this: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://... ..._vti_bin/Lists.asmx"

Comment: If you check your ULS / EventLogs, does anything show up hinting as to why you received the 500?

Comment: hmmm,
"List does not exist.
    The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user"
The list is definitely there... and it works if it's not in the CEWP.

Comment: Is it possible you're trying to access a list in a different site/sub-site?  One common problem I run into is accessing the root vti_bin when I need to actually access the sub-site vti_bin and vice versa.

Comment: Oh wow, I think that is the problem! It's trying to find the Lists.asmx of the subsite, not the root site's Lists.asmx.
How would you suggest pointing it to the root site's Lists.asmx? I'm not sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to access the root site.  If, for some reason, you simply can't use ECMAScript

```
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb();  //this is the web object
var url = clientContext.get_site().Url; //this is the root url
var listServiceUrl = url + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
```

You could always use `location.host + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"` if that's safe in your current setup.